# Serialize table with details

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I want to rearrange below order numbers using update statement but keep the same order number for each order line

```
order_date  Order_Number  Order_Line
-------------------------------------
2015-01-06      1               1
2015-01-06      1               2
2015-01-06      6               1
2015-01-06      6               2
2015-01-06      9               1
2015-01-06      9               2
2015-01-06      9               3
2015-01-06      11              1
2015-01-06      11              2
2015-01-06      11              3
2015-01-06      11              4
```

I have tried to run this :

```
DECLARE @OrdN INT = 0 

UPDATE hist_line 
SET @OrdN = order_number = @OrdN + 1 
WHERE order_date = '06/01/2015'
```

but it returns a new serial for each line while it should look like this :

```
order_date  Order_Number  Order_Line
-------------------------------------
2015-01-06      1               1
2015-01-06      1               2
2015-01-06      2               1
2015-01-06      2               2
2015-01-06      3               1
2015-01-06      3               2
2015-01-06      3               3
2015-01-06      4               1
2015-01-06      4               2
2015-01-06      4               3
2015-01-06      4               4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank()`:

```
select order_date,
       dense_rank() over (partition by order_date order by Order_Number) as Order_Number,
       Order_Line
from t;
```

This is an ANSI-standard function, available in most databases.

EDIT:

To actually do the update, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by order_date order by Order_Number) as new_Order_Number
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set Order_Number = new_Order_Number;
```